# Nesting Fields within Views

Tags: ios, swift

First and foremost, I am not using Apple's storyboard.  I want the freedom to create applications without the constraints that are applied using their out-of-the-box features.  Is there a way to nest objects within one another. For example, two UITextFields found within a UIView.  This is programmatically and not on the scene it self.  I know you can two text fields found within the UIView on the actual scene itself.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about.

```
    let credentials: UIView = {
    let credential = UIView()

    let CredUserName: UITextField = {
        let username = UITextField()
        username.placeholder = "Username"
        return username
    }()

    let CredPassword: UITextField = {
        let password = UITextField()
        password.placeholder = "Password"
        return password
    }()

    return credential
} ()
```

If it's not possible then I will separate them.

Thanks!

Comment: "two UITextFields found within a UIView" Those are called subviews.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ - Just looking at the UIView docs would have told you about `addSubview` (especially after I _told_ you the name of the concept).

Comment: Appreciate the comment.  I will put in more of an attempt despite the attempts I have already made on my own

Comment: By the way, there is very little you can do in code that you can't do in Storyboards. For example, you can easily drag a UIView into a storyboard scene, add some UITextFields to it as subviews and so on

Comment: By the way, storyboards/xibs don't limit you at all, there are no constrains, no chains. It's just a simplification of the view creation with automatic validations and instant preview. If you don't want it, you can make it the hard way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `UIView.addSubView()`

```
let credentials: UIView = {
    let credential = UIView()

    let CredUserName: UITextField = {
        let username = UITextField()
        username.placeholder = "Username"
        return username
    }()

    let CredPassword: UITextField = {
        let password = UITextField()
        password.placeholder = "Password"
        return password
    }()

    credential.addSubView(CredUserName)
    credential.addSubView(CredPassword)

    return credential
} ()
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.  I thought I had to add (view.addSubview(credentials.CredUserName)) which obviously wasn't working.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: @ButtahNBred, `password.isSecureTextEntry = true` if you want.